# The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, package.json, webpack-4, nodemon

**Project directory structure**.

[image]

Below are the `webpack` configuration files.

**webpack.config.client.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CURRENT_WORKING_DIR = process.cwd();

const config = {
  name: 'browser',
  mode: 'development',
  // mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    path.join(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, 'client/main.js'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, '/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      // To bundle image assets so that other JS code can also access
      // and load it other than the component in which it was imported into.
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|gif|jpg|png)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
    },
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

**webpack.config.server.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const CURRENT_WORKING_DIR = process.cwd();

const config = {
  name: 'server',
  entry: [path.join(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, './server/server.js')],
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, '/dist/'),
    filename: 'server.generated.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      // To bundle image assets so that other JS code can also access
      // and load it other than the component in which it was imported into.
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|gif|jpg|png)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

**webpack.client.production.js**

```js
// const path = require('path');
// const CURRENT_WORKING_DIR = process.cwd();

// const config = {
//   mode: 'production',
//   entry: [path.join(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, 'client/main.js')],
//   output: {
//     path: path.join(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, '/dist'),
//     filename: 'bundle.js',
//     publicPath: '/dist/',
//   },
//   module: {
//     rules: [
//       {
//         test: /\.jsx?$/,
//         exclude: /node_modules/,
//         use: ['babel-loader'],
//       },
//       // To bundle image assests so that other JS code can also access
//       // and load it other than the component in which it was imported into.
//       {
//         test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|gif|jpg|png)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
//         use: 'file-loader',
//       },
//     ],
//   },
// };

// module.exports = config;
```

When I try `yarn build` , I get the following error.

```sh
 WARNING in configuration
    The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.
    Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
    You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

    ERROR in main
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/home/prithvi/Desktop/socialize'
    resolve './src' in '/home/prithvi/Desktop/socialize'
      using description file: /home/prithvi/Desktop/socialize/package.json (relative path: .)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        using description file: /home/prithvi/Desktop/socialize/package.json (relative path: ./src)
          no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/prithvi/Desktop/socialize/src doesn't exist
          .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/prithvi/Desktop/socialize/src.js doesn't exist
          .json
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/prithvi/Desktop/socialize/src.json doesn't exist
          .wasm
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/prithvi/Desktop/socialize/src.wasm doesn't exist
          as directory
            /home/prithvi/Desktop/socialize/src doesn't exist

    webpack 5.31.0 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 256 ms
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Below are the **scripts config** & **dependencies** from **package.json** file.

```js
"main": "./dist/server.generated.js",
"scripts": {
    "development": "nodemon",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.client.production.js && webpack --mode=production --config webpack.config.server.js",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server.generated.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
    "helmet": "^4.4.1",
    "jshint": "^2.12.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "webpack": "^5.24.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
}
```

Comment: What do you have in `webpack.config.client.production.js`?

Comment: updated it. Though, `webpack.client.production.js` has been commented out as I'm using `devBundle.js` for development purpose.

Comment: But your `build` script in `package.json` is using it `"webpack --config webpack.config.client.production.js && webpack --mode=production --config webpack.config.server.js"`.

Comment: But that shouldn't effect as `webpack.client.production.js` is empty !?

Comment: It does matter as far as I can tell from the error. Webpack is trying to read the default entry from './src' and there's no such file.

Comment: Got it ! 
I just had to remove `production` file and replace with `development` file in `package.json`.
Thanks @chenxsan !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image]

```
const path = require('path'); // libreria
module.exports = {
entry: './js/app.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'), 
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
mode: 'development'}
```

Adding the `mode:development` command solves the problem.

[image]

Comment: As you're on the English language version of Stack Overflow, please make sure that all explanatory text is also in English. Also, images that contain mostly text are usually better suited as actual text, so they're more accessible to screen readers and search engines.

Answer (score 5):

If you get this warning, the solution is quite simple:

webpack.config.js

```
 const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
  const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

  module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production', //add this line here
  });
```

source: https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-mode

Reason: I just did a huge version update and got this warning, luckily it's your situation also

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and after doing research on it, I found a solution i.e., we need to update our 'package.json' file, there are no changes required in your 'webpack.config.js' file.

Please add the following changes to your 'package.json' file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
```

I hope, it will work for you.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the 'mode' option to the webpack config object:

```
const current_mode = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';

let config = {
 devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
 mode: current_mode,
```